# Multiple datasources for searchbox

Tags: google-app-maker

I have integrated a 'Header' pagefragment that contains a searchbox into my review app. The searchbox allows me to search for employees in the Directory model, but I would also like to search in the reviews.

The query builder in the Review model goes like this

```
  FamilyName contains? :SearchText or
  GivenName contains? :SearchText or
  EmployeeEmail contains? :SearchText or
  CostCenter contains? :SearchText or
  Location contains? :SearchText
```

When I am on the Review dashboard, I would like the datasource of the searchbox switch from the Directory model to the Review model. I have therefore created the following binding:

```
(@currentPage == @pages.Dashboard) ? 
@datasources.Reviews.query.parameters.SearchText : 
@datasource.query.keywords
```

But when I access the page in the preview the console returns an 'invalid binding' message. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that App Maker is smart enough to digest such type of binding for an input widget. I would recommend you to follow the pattern used in [Training Hub](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/training-hub/) template:

1. set some arbitrary datasource for the header page fragment
2. bind search box to `@datasource.query.parameters.SearchText`
3. override datasource for the page fragment on every page where you need it
   [image: override datasource]

Your particular use case will require slightly more fancy leg movements. Since for actual search you need different things from the query, you'll need to

1. Switch your `Directory` datasource to `query script` mode
2. Introduce `SearchText` query parameter
3. Add this query script to the datasource

```javascript
query.keywords = query.parameters.SearchText;

return query.run();
```

With such adjustments all your datasources will expose the same interface and could have different implementations.